# reading value attached to a variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi below is a section of my code. I dont get the desired out put for `else if ( txt3Val.value >= txt4Val )` but if I adjust it to `else if ( document.getElementById('txt3') >= document.getElementById('txt4') )` it works. Can someone tell me why this happens? Thanks.

```
......AND THE CODE READS
    else if(document.form1.GWchk.checked == true) 
        {
        var txt3Val = document.getElementById('txt3');
        var txt4Val = document.getElementById('txt4');
            if(txt3Val.value == "" || txt4Val.value == "")
            {
                alert ("You need to enter both starting and ending number \nof the cheque book for GlW."); return false;
            }
            else if ( txt3Val.value >= txt4Val ) 
            { 
                alert ("Ending cheque number should be of greater value"); return false;
            }
            else
            {
            alert ("Successfully saved your entry1."); return false;
            }
        }
```

**HIGHLIGHT :** Sorry the code `else if ( txt3Val.value >= txt4Val.value )` also doesnt work! Actually that's what its there on my real script a re-write error here. But the my preoblem remains the same where it doesnt give me the ending number should be greate.... and straight goes to successfully saved.

**EDIT** I think I figure out something. On the first text box if I put '10' as a value and second as '9' then JS seems doesn't recognize 9 as a lower value. But if I put '09' it gives the desired out put. How do I handle this?

Comment: How are you going to compare two HTML elements? Use the corresponding member according to the nature, i.e. `value` for `<input>`

Comment: Did you mean `txt4Val.value` in that if statement?

Comment: Shouldnt it be "else if ( txt3Val.value >= txt4Val.value )" instead of "else if ( txt3Val.value >= txt4Val )"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if( parseInt( txt3Val.value, 10 ) >=  parseInt( txt4Val.value, 10 ) )
```

Answer (score 3):

try changing:

```
else if ( txt3Val.value >= txt4Val )
```

to

```
else if ( txt3Val.value >= txt4Val.value )
```

Answer (score 2):

```
else if ( txt3Val.value >= txt4Val )
```

should be

```
else if ( txt3Val.value >= txt4Val.value )
```

Answer (score 0):

Using comparisons again HTML elements isn't going to give you your desired result. Append `.value` to the end of `txt4Val` to access the value from that element:

```
else if ( txt3Val.value >= txt4Val.value ) {

}
```